# T-SQL error handling with try catch rollback, error rows were deleted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, commit

I have the following construct. I noticed that erroneous rows where error number was clearly > 0 was being deleted at the end of the while loop. I don't understand where i have gone wrong with the error catching. Do i need the second commit in the catch section to commit the update of the error number?

```
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin try
    begin transaction 
        [...insert something into a table here...]
        set @countrec = @countrec + @@rowcount 

    update Alarmtable
        set success = 0
      where Recno = @recno

    commit transaction 

  end try
  begin catch
    if @@trancount > 0 rollback transaction

    select @error = error_number()
         , @errormsg = error_message()  

    update Alarmtable 
      set success = @error 
    where Recno = @recno

    if @@trancount > 0 commit transaction

  end catch

  fetch next from listofrecords into 
        @recno, @alarmcontent

end /* while */

close listofrecords 
deallocate listofrecords 

delete Alarmtable 
   where success = 0
```

Comment: remove `if @@trancount > 0 commit transaction` in the catch block. I don't see any need to have it there

Comment: Can you post your entire code including the one which inserts into `Alarmtable`

Comment: Removing commit in the catch block worked for me. For reasons i don't understand, this was the statement that caused the error rows to get deleted. I thought the first rollback in the catch would have emptied everything before. My extra commit transaction actually commits a zero to success column. The error number in the success column doesn't need a commit to save correctly. Thanks @kevchadders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the commit transaction and the error entries don't get removed anymore. Thanks @kevchadders.